# Change to function Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below, it works as expected, but I need to pass the id of each one to work.
How can I turn it into a function to use the `onKeyPress` event:

```
document.getElementById('inp').addEventListener('input', e => {
const val = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0*/, '').padStart(3, '0')
e.target.value = val.slice(0, -2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.') + ',' + val.slice(-2)
})
```

I would like to turn to use as a: `function Mask(){ // code }`

```
<input asp-for="Frete" name="Frete" onKeyPress="return(Mask(this,'.',',',event))" class="form-control" />
```

To be able to use the `function`, so I would need to create one by one by `id`

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: What do you mean "each one"?  An id selector is only going to match at most one element

Comment: In this way, I need to pass the id of the input, and I've created a function, which is already being passed to all forms that I need.I will edit the question.

Comment: @zer00ne A JavaScript function is defined with the function keyword, followed by a name, followed by parentheses ().

Function names can contain letters, digits, underscores, and dollar signs (same rules as variables).

The parentheses may include parameter names separated by commas:
(parameter1, parameter2, ...)

The code to be executed, by the function, is placed inside curly brackets: {}

Comment: @Raymond There's also arrow function in JS, that is used in the OP's example.

Comment: @zer00ne `(...} is not the same as `{ }`. It is receiving a callback and we are grabbing the value.

Comment: @marianac_costa are you after event delegation, i.e. a way you could add the keypress event to multiple input elements without specifying each element with an id?

Comment: @Raymond typo `{...}` = `{...}` it's pseudocode for:  *"copy contents of one brack to the new bracket"*

Comment: @zer00ne no she had responded that. Asking about the addEventListener. When you ask what does she not understand

Comment: @Raymond then step in and help the OP I'm not the one that needs  the help.

Comment: I would like to take advantage of a single code, for not having redundancy code, otherwise I will have to create one for each input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go you could use `event` object like :

```js
document.getElementById('inp1').addEventListener('input', (e) => { Mask(e, 'inp1'); });
document.getElementById('inp2').addEventListener('input', (e) => { Mask(e, 'inp2'); });
document.getElementById('inp3').addEventListener('input', (e) => { Mask(e, 'inp3'); });

function Mask(e, id) {
  const target = document.getElementById(id);

  const val = target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').replace(/^0*/, '').padStart(3, '0');
  target.value = val.slice(0, -2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1.') + ',' + val.slice(-2);
}
```

```html
<input id="inp1">
<input id="inp2">
<input id="inp3">
```

Comment: Error: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at Mask (Clientes.js:1001)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeypress